# Why does reset_sequences=True cause pytest to actually flush differences to the test_database?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, unit-testing, pytest

I'm running my django tests using pytest and I saw some strange behaviour. To find out what happened I put a `breakpoint()` in my tests and then psql'ed into my postgres database to see what the status was. To my surprise all database tables were empty even though when using MyModel.objects.all().count() gave about 500 (test) records.

I looked up [the documentation](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#pytest.mark.django_db) and fiddled around a bit, and then found out that when I change

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
```

at the top of my tests to

```
@pytest.mark.django_db(reset_sequences=True)
```

the counts I see when psql'ing into postgres show the same as what I get from doing a count using the django orm.

To add to the confusion, the documentation actually says that `reset_sequences=True`

> Must be used together with transaction=True to have an effect.

Why does setting `reset_sequences` to `True` have the effect that doing a count using psql has the same effect as doing a count using the django ORM?

Comment: "To my surprise all database tables were empty" -> this would be expected if the tests are run in a transaction that rolls back at the end of the test.  It's possible that `reset_sequences` triggers a commit somehow, making the test data persist in the db.

Comment: @snakecharmerb - I'm also thinking along that line. I just don't see anything like that in the documentation, which is why I was wondering whether someone knows this for sure. Plus, I would like to know the rationale behind triggering commits when sequences must be reset. Because if the commit is simply rolled back, then the sequences don't even need to be reset. But I guess my idea behind this is wrong, and I don't know why.